# Dropdow menu keyboard responsive issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm really new with building website, I'm trying to make this dropdown menu keyboard responsive but is not working.

Now I can tab on the links and displays the drop menu.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/q7m8s/

CSS:

```
   #menu{
        width:200px;
        background:#444;
    }
    .noBullets
    {
        list-style: none;
        padding-left: 0px;  
    }
    #menu li a{
        padding:15px;
    }
    #menu a{
        display:block;
        color:#fff;
    }
    #menu ul ul{
        display:none;
        background:#000;
    }
    #menu ul ul a:hover{
        background:#222;
    }
```

HTML

```
<div id="menu">
<ul class="noBullets">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a>
      <ul>
      <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Direcctions</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Form</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">ontact Us</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

JS: (Updated thanks to Carlos)

```
    $('#menu li:has(ul)').hover(function(){
        $(this).find('> ul').stop().slideToggle(400); 
    });

   $('#menu li:has(ul)').focusin(function(){
    $(this).find('> ul').stop().slideToggle(400); 
});
```

Comment: looks good. Nice work

Comment: @derek_duncan But is not keyboard responsive :/

Comment: What do you mean by "keyboard responsive"? BTW, http://jsfiddle.net/q7m8s/1/

Comment: @bjb568 I updated the question and the fiddle, try using using the keyboard key(tab) It will open the menu

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
Remove:

```
$("#menu li:has(ul)").focus(function()
 {
     $(this).parents("li").addClass("hover");
 }).blur(function()
 {
     $(this).parents("li").removeClass("hover");
 });
```

To:

```
$('#menu li:has(ul)').focusin(function(){
    $(this).find('> ul').stop().slideToggle(400); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but how can I keep the dropmenu open

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your js to this instead:

```
$('#menu li:has(ul)').hover(function(){
    $(this).find('> ul').stop().slideToggle(400); 
});

$('#menu li:has(ul)').focusin(function(){
    $(this).find('> ul').stop().slideToggle(400); 
});
$( '#menu li:has(ul)' ).keydown(function( event ) {
if ( event.which == 9 ) {
    event.preventDefault();
$(this).find('> ul').stop().slideToggle(400);
}});
```

Just added a key event on tab to open the menu